# Coffeescript equivalent of python 'pass' statement

Tags: syntax, coffeescript

In Python one can use the 'pass' statement to do nothing:

```
if true:
    pass
```

Is there a similar statement in coffeescript?
I'm trying to do a switch statement and do nothing if certain conditions are met.

```
switch variable:
  when 5 then pass
  else do variable
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

i'm a happy user of

```
switch x
  when 1
   null
  when 2
   y = 3
  else
   y = 4
```

since `null` is already in the language and does semantically transport that meaning of 'nothing'.

Comment: This is my favorite answer, but I wonder if using `;` would be (a very tiny bit) more efficient than `null`?

Answer (score 17):

Unlike in Python, empty blocks are (usually) valid in CoffeeScript.  So you can simply use:

```
switch variable:
  when 5 then
  else
    variable
```

Note that without the `then` it won't compile, which I find a bit odd.  This works pretty generally, though:

```
if x
else if y
  something()
else
  somethingElse()
```

is perfectly valid CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 8):

Because every expression has a value in CoffeeScript, a `pass` keyword, if it existed, would be equivalent to the value `undefined`. So, you could define

```
pass = undefined
```

and then use `pass` just like in Python:

```
switch variable
   when 5
     pass
   else
     do variable
```

Answer (score 6):

I always use a semicolon for this:

```
switch variable
  when 5 then ;
  else do variable
```

This is because in javascript, a semicolon is a valid statement which also happens to do nothing.

**Update**: I just thought of another interesting way of doing this. You could define `pass` as a global variable and set it to `undefined`:

```
window.pass = undefined

switch variable
  when 5 then pass
  else do variable
```

The only thing you have to watch out for is using `pass` as a local variable or redefining the global `pass` variable. That would break your code.

If you use Google's closure compiler, you could annotate this variable so that it is a constant:

```
`/** @const */ var pass;`
```

But then it would have to go at the beginning of each file. You could write your own preprocessor to do that automatically, though.

Answer (score 1):

This makes sense to me in coffeescript:

```
switch variable
    when "a" then doSomething()
    when "b" then break
```

This compiles to the following js:

```
switch (variable) {
    case "a":
        doSomething();
        break;
    case "b":
        break;
}
```

Note: You shouldn't use null like @flow suggests, because it inserts an unnecessary statement like this

```
null;
```

Comment: this works well with switch statements, but doesn't fully fill in for `pass` because it can't be used in an if/else like pass can.